# Am I correct in calculating/getting this answer? (Exponent Laws)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

Sorry for the formatting of the maths, I dont know why its bunching up. Tried to add the multiplication sign in to make it more readable.

So the question was:

\begin{equation}
\frac{x^{-7}\cdot y^2}{(\sqrt[4]{x}\cdot  z)^6
}
\end{equation}

when written in the form $x^ay^bz^c$ what is the value of $a$?

I first calculated it as $17/2$:

\begin{equation}
\frac{x^{-7}\cdot y^2}{(\sqrt[4]{x})^6\cdot (z)^6 
}\longrightarrow
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\frac{x^{-7}\cdot y^2}{(x^\frac{3}{2})(z)^6 
}\longrightarrow
\end{equation}

then by dividing the x values:

\begin{equation}x^\frac{17}{2}y^2 z^6
\end{equation}

but then by using simple exponent rules  (ie. $x^{m-n}$ ) I ended up getting $x^{-\frac{17}{2}}$.

Which one of these answers is correct (if either is). If neither are could you please tell me the correct way?

Comment: Tip: You can use \cdot to make a $\cdot$ as a multiplication sign instead of $*$

Comment: The second one  is correct. I don't know how you missed he minus sign in the first.

Comment: Exactly, just calculate $-7-\frac 3 2$ and you will get $-\frac{17}{2}$

Answer (score 1):

-17/2 is correct. In your first answer, the exponent corresponding to z should be -6 as it is in the denominator. Once you realise why it is -6 and not 6 for z then same applies to x